# Quotes Within Quotes Issues

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a textbox that will be displayed on my website. When displayed, I'd like to show some data within the text box. Here is what I have

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"100\" value=\"<a href=\"$url\"></a>\">";
```

All that shows up in the text box is `<a href=`
And then at the end of the text box, right after the text box I see `">`

I know something must be syntactically off, just not sure what.

Comment: what shows up in the textbox? It'd help if you'd post your code.

Comment: @Hydrangea: Edited :-) Just a markdown parsing error or something.

Answer (score 2):

You must encode `<`, `"`, and `>` chars - they can't be embedded that way. Use:

```
echo '<input type="text" size="100" value="'.htmlspecialchars('<a href="'.$url.'"></a>').'">';
```

You may also use `urlencode()` function - see which suits you better.

One more tip - use single quotes when string contains HTML-like content. This will save you adding `\"` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. That part-way solved the issue. Here is what I got in the textbox <a href="$url"></a>

Comment: This is correct content. You can't embed links in `<input>` contents as you do in HTML.

Comment: @Charlie Try `htmlspecialchars('<a href="'.$url.'"></a>')`.

Comment: @trutheality Thank you very much that fixed the problem. The people on this forum never cease to amaze me with how brilliant you all are.

Comment: This was an 'eagle eye' one. I've simply copied part of the string and didn't notice that contexts changed. ;]

Comment: I was asking indirectly, if you can accept my answer. ;] If you accept people's answer, they are more willin to answer your next questions. ;]

Answer (score 0):

```
php_code ?>
<input type="text" size="100" value="<a href=&quote;<?=$url;?>&quote;></a>\">
<?php
php_code
```

maybe this will work for you

Comment: Quite a good solution except one should avoid using `<?=`. Correct it quickly before anyone spots it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think of what the html would look like:

```
<input type="text" size="100" value="<a href="$url"></a>">
                                             ^
                                             |
                                             This is where the value attribute ends!
```

`htmlspecialchars` should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistake. Your code will result in something like that (also visible in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDUHd/1/)):

```
<input type="text" size="100" value="<a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>">
```

Instead you can use something like that:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"100\" value=\"&lt;a href=&quot;$url&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;\">";
```

or

```
echo '<input type="text" size="100" value="&lt;a href=&quot;' . $url . '&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;">';
```

to receive effect visible in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDUHd/). Is it satisfying enough?